# jqueryで要素の属性で絞り込む方法はありますか?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

html

```
<a href="hoge">1</a>
<a href="huga">2</a>
<a href="hogehoge">3</a>
<a href="hugahuga">4</a>
```

jquery

```
$('a').onAttr('href', 'hoge'); // 1のjqueryオブジェクト
$('a').onAttr('href', 'huga'); // 2のjqueryオブジェクト
$('a').onAttr('href', /hoge/); // 1,4のjqueryオブジェクト
$('a').onAttr('href', /huga/); // 2,3のjqueryオブジェクト
```

このように'href'がマッチした要素を取得したいのですが、どのようにしたらよいのでしょうか。
`a`を取得して`each`で回してチェックするやり方しか思いつきません・・・。

Comment: http://semooh.jp/jquery/api/selectors/%5Battribute+value%5D/
属性フィルタは使えませんか？

Comment: 部分一致はどうしたらよいのでしょうか?

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございます。
`$('a[href*="部分マッチ"]')`

Comment: ご自身で回答を作成しチェックをつけると、評価があがりますし、後から読む人の為にもなりますよ。

Answer (score 1):

[user7339さんコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/7215/#comment6369_7215)：

> 解決しました。ありがとうございます。`$('a[href*="部分マッチ"]')`